# How to Implement a (statistical) Thematic Comparison of Texts via Text-Mining?

Tags: python, text-mining, gensim, text-classification, lda

I try to compare texts in form of 'text-files' concerning their content.
**e.g.**: I got 100 texts about animals and I want to analyze each text about what animals it discusses.
I am looking for an analysis output like: `doc1: 60% cats, 10% rabbits, 10% dogs, 0% elephants, 20% else", "doc2: 0% cats, 10% rabbits, 40% dogs, ...`

I have read a lot about Latent Dirichlet Allocation (and the word-probabilities for each topic) for Text Classification but a completely unsupervised approach seemed not to fit my set of documents.

Trying to implement the LDA-Stuff in Python I understood to prepare the data (tokenizing, lemmatizing/stemming) but I don't get the next steps. Do I have to generate training data for each topic (animal) and how could I implement this?

Also I've seen a tutorial manipulating the topics via the `eta-value` in `gensim` but I don't know how I could use this in my favor.

I am grateful for any advice that can lead me to the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: what is your Determination of what constitutes "talking about cats"? Does it involve number of times "cat" or "cats" occur in the document?

Comment: I think of how many times "cat" occurs, but also terms that are related to cats ("kitten", "meow",...). Therefore I probably need an approach like the LDA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use LDA you're done with proprocessing (tokenizing, stemming/lemmatizing), the next step would be to create `gensim` dictionary and corpus. Assuming your set of documents is a list of lists like `[['my', 'first', 'doc'], ['the', 'second', 'doc']]` you could proceed like this:

```
dictionary = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(texts)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
```

Then create your model with appropriate number of topics (=animals):

```
model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=num_animals)
```

You don't need to generate training data yourself at all. After a number of iterations, the LDA algorithm itself performs a quality check on a set of randomly chosen held out test documents which were not used for training. The corresponding measure is often called "perplexity" or "log likelihood" and will usually be displayed during iteration.

When your model is finally created you can have a look at the words in your topics:

```
model.print_topics()
```

In many cases, you have a collection of documents and a rough idea of the number of topics contained. So the most relevant parameter to play around with is the topic number. 
Since you already know your topic number, you are left to tinker with other parameters. I could imagine that it's difficult to get topics that can be easily attributed to precisely one animal. Keep in mind though that every word appears in every topic, so even "elephant" is going to show up in the "cat" topic somewhere.

Things to try:

- Be more rigorous with your stemming/lemmatization to merge more tokens with the same meaning
- Check out `filter_extremes` function of your dictionary to filter for very common or very rare tokens
- Apply or expand your stopword filter to get rid of irrelevant terms
- Play around with alpha (prevalence of topics per document) and eta (prevalence of tokens per topic) values

Comment: thank you! I tried out performing LDA that way and it seems that it's not really appropriate for my exercise.